# what would be the most efficient way to get the last videos my friends share on facebook (json)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have the list of all posts, and i can filter by only videos but for example in 20 posts just 2 posts are videos and i want the last 20 videos like showyou, shelby etc does

ps: please provide a example code if possible ;) this is for videos posted on facebook from youtube, vimeo etc. (embed videos)

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

You can go for using FQL for [video](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video/).

Comment: not work because the video page is about the videos that you upload to facebook and not the videos from external content partners like youtube, vimeo etc

Comment: You could query the link table, and then check if the url contains strings like "youtube", "vimeo"..etc. Here is the link to the link table: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/links/

Comment: i'm doing that, using the field "type=video" i get all the posts and then filter them by type is ok but the problem is get for example 20 posts (text, videos, and other status updates) using this " https://graph.facebook.com/me/home" (test here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and get only the 20 video posts, now they show me only the videos in the last 20 posts (check the website alpha.shelby.tv for you understand better what i want )